# Wordpress - Find the form-handler file with the route action

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a form like this in one of my files

```
<form action="/uploads/#wpcf7-f233-p2-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
```

I don't know where is this form-handler. In Symfony there is a routing file where you find with each route, the Controller and the Action called so it's easy to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the code of WPCF7 in `wp-content/plugins/wpcf7/`.  Grep for `do_action` and identify the hooks.

Then write a custom function and register it in your theme or own plugin.

Below an  example for the `before_send_mail` hook.

```php
function wpcf7_ba_before_send_mail($cf7) {
    global $wpdb;
    $cfid = $cf7->id();
    error_log("Hit wpcf7_ba_before_send_mail with id: ".$cfid);


    /* This is the ID of your form  */
    if ($cfid==1850) {

        /* Get the form object */
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance(); 

        /* Get posted data */
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

        /* change receiver */
        $recs = explode(',', $posted_data['mailto']);
        $mails = Array();
        foreach ( $recs as $r ) {
            $m = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT mail,name FROM webservice_cache WHERE id='$r'");
            $t = $m[0]->mail ? $m[0]->mail : '';
            array_push($mails,$t);
        }
        $mail = $cf7->prop('mail');
        $bccs = join(',', $mails);
        error_log('Would mail to: '.$bccs);
        $mail['additional_headers'] =  Bcc:foo@example.com,bar@example.com\r\nReply-To:foobar@example.com\r\n";
        /* persist changes in form object */
        $cf7->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );
    }

    return $cf7;
}

/* register your custom function to be called on 
 * do_action before_send_mail.
 */
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_ba_before_send_mail", 10, 1);
```

The code is based on [this resource](http://contactform7.com/2014/07/02/contact-form-7-39-beta/). Just make shure, you use the new syntax to update your form object.

P.S. Avoid downvotes by registering  to [wordpress.sackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)